# R.appにて、CSVファイルを読み込み、各行の統計値を計算して、結果を保存したい

Tags: r

test.R を下記のように書きましたが、わからない部分があり、ご教示いただきたく存じます。
・CSVファイルを読み込んだあと、各行の値を読み込む方法がよくわかりません。
・最頻値の関数はないのでしょうか

```
#CSVファイルを読み込む
read.csv("testfile.csv")

#A行を呼び出す
？
#統計値を求める
#平均
mean(a)
#中央値
median(a)
#最頻値
？
#計算した統計値を結果をデータに保存する
sink("result.csv")
```

読み込むcsvファイルのサンプル

```
A,B,C
1123124,1123125,1123125
1123131,1123132,1123132
1123256,1123257,1123257
1123381,1123382,1123382
1123506,1123507,1123507
1123631,1123632,1123632
1123756,1123757,1123757
1123881,1123882,1123882
1124006,1124007,1124007
1124131,1124132,1124132
1124256,1124257,1124257
1124381,1124382,1124382
1124506,1124507,1124507
1124631,1124632,1124632
1124756,1124757,1124757
1124881,1124882,1124882
1125006,1125007,1125007
1125131,1125132,1125132
1125256,1125257,1125257
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- read.csv("testfile.csv")
```

などとして、`read.csv`の結果を変数`a`に束縛すると、以降その中身を`a`として利用できるようになります。

```
print(a$A) # あるいはprint(a[, 'A'])
```

で列Aを表示します。

最頻値を求める方法はいくつかあるとおもいますが、
例えば以下のようにして算出できます。

```
names(which.max(table(a$A)))
```

Comment: この最頻値算出関数は、同率1位が複数ある場合には不適格ですので、ご注意ください。